# Pause selenium script for an hour, Is it a bad automation practice?If yes, why?

Tags: selenium, automation

I have an automation scenario where script need to wait for an hour to perform further verification. This is very important scenario for my client business. But I am thinking its not a good automation practice to wait for an hour though its possible.

I provided alternative solutions to automate this case without pausing for an hour. Though its not covering 100% of my client requirement. Can any one suggest based on your experience what are the cons of keeping hard sleep in automation ( if it really requires)? And whether its a good practice or not ?If not, why?

Comment: Please share more details on your Scenario OR Use case.

Comment: Once new user complete their registration, on home page user will see a menu e.g."ABCD". After an hour that menu should change to something else e.g. "EFGH".

Comment: Wait for one hour is to long. few months back we have a module in which we have to wait for 2 hours to get response. To over come that issue  we opted service virtualization to get  response

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass it by Token. You may take help from Developer to bypass it. 
Token will allow to Enable that Menu after Registration. So it will continue your Selenium script and You do not need to wait for 1 hour.

Comment: Thanks Ishita for your quick response! As I mentioned in my question, I have multiple solutions which might works.I am not really looking for any other solution. But the reason I posted this question is want to understand the real problems with pausing the script for more duration. Why it's not a good practice, generally why people think for alternative solutions to solve this type of problem statements.

Comment: If you don't want any other solution, Yes, Its your choice only. I even do not see any positive point of your problem statement by waiting 1 hour of Duration. As far, Script are meant with minutes of execution.